# One Crayz but nice to underestand on KitKat Choclate?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

anyone can help me to understand what is the translation of words in a box that I draw a circle on it in the following KitKat Picture into English? (what is the words top of 5% in English)? it's so strange for me to read it because my native is Spanish.

[image]

any idea?

Comment: There is one asterix (`*`) and two (`**`) which mean there are corresponding footnotes somewhere at the bottom of the box, but the bottom is missing...  "На порцию 23,5 г 124 ккал" means "A portion of 23.5 grams contains 124 kcalories".

Comment: @YellowSky 5% means 5 percent kcalories in one day?

Comment: I guess it means it contains 5% of fat.

Comment: @Suarez `5% means 5 percent kcalories in one day?` Yes, it means 5% of the day man norm (2500 kcal * 5% = 125 kcal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple;

***на порцию 23,5 г*** = per portion of 23,5 g / por cada ración de 23,5 g;

***ккал*** = kcal (a unit of energetical value of food).

*Trivia: in Ukranian (another East-Slavic language) the words kit-kat could be understood as 'cat the executioner' (gato el verdugo).*

Comment: very thanks, but I couldn't get the point about 5% !

Comment: Could be either an advertising joke or, as YS said, some data is missing.